# ActiveMerchant Cybersource Authorization Error Reason 102

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, cybersource

I'm work on debugging an application that is currently running on `Ruby 2.5.8` with `ActiveMerchant 1.117.0`.

I am able to create and save the subscription successfully.  However, when I try to authorize the saved card I keep getting `reasonCode 102`.  The error from the Cybersource gateway side is `the subscription () could not be found`.

I'm attempting to authorize with the function:

```
  def authorize(token, amount, order_id, line_items)
    response = gateway.authorize(amount, token, order_id: order_id, line_items: line_items)
    if !response.success?
      raise Exceptions::ChargeFailed.new(response.message, response: response)
    end
    response
  end
```

The error would lead me to believe that the formatting here is not correct.  Can anyone point me to some working ActiveMerchant CyberSource examples for authorizing a subscription or point out what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, it appears that the logic for token assignment changed inside of the ActiveMerchant CyberSource gem

The original logic was:

```
if reference
    _, subscription_id, _ = reference.split(";")
    xml.tag! 'subscriptionID',  subscription_id
end
```

The latest versions this shifted towards:

```
if reference
    subscription_id = reference.split(";")[6]
    xml.tag! 'subscriptionID',  subscription_id
end
```

The application that I am working with previously had been formatting the CyberSource profile / subscription id as `;#{token};`.  In order to work with these latest updates the token needs to be formatted as `;;;;;;#{token}`.